# How do I pass my parameter when trying to execute SSH commands in HUDSON

Tags: continuous-integration, hudson

I want my job to do some commands on other servers.  I've created a new (parameterized) job that simply executes shell commands.

I can't figure out how to get my build parameter to get passed along to the command line of the remote.

```
ssh myservername 'echo ${MY_PARAMETER}'
```

Looking at my console output I see:

```
+ ssh myservername echo ${MY_PARAMETER}
```

What I want to see is:

```
+ ssh myservername echo MyValueFromTheBuild
```

There must be a way to make this happen.

Comment: I guess I should add the fact that I'm ssh'ing into a Linux box with a bash shell.

Comment: Using single quotes in your shell command means the environment variable won't be expanded. @Soo Wei Tan has the answer.

Comment: Was this ever answered?

Comment: Perhaps it was the version of the plugin I was using at the time, but the answer by neillb, is the one that worked for my case.  I'm guessing that the Soo Wei Tan answer worksed for the Jenkins provided parameters only.  I was trying to pass parameters that were passed into the job as input fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
bash -c "ssh myservername 'echo ${MY_PARAMETER}'"
```

Note that here the variable's value on the local machine is used.  It won't yield the value of the variable on the remote host.  From the context it sounds like the former is what you want.

As ever, be careful not to evaluate input you don't have complete control over.

Answer (score 2):

I use this on our Jenkins server and it works just fine for me.

`ssh myservername "echo $PROJECTNAME"`

Answer (score 0):

My **guess** would be to try one of the following syntax forms:

```
ssh myservername 'echo $MY_PARAMETER'
ssh myservername 'echo ${ENV, var="MY_PARAMETER"}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but that gives the same result.

Comment: Updated to include another option.

Comment: Different result:
bash: ${env, var="MY_PARAMETER"}: bad substitution